# Is it possible to stop the calculator in notification centre resetting to 0 when opened?

Tags: high-sierra, notifications

When using the calculator in the notification centre I often type some numbers, close the notification centre to check some notes on another window, then re-open notification centre to add the next operand to a calculation.
However, when I re-open the notification centre the calculator always resets to zero!

Is there any way to persist the current calculation and stop the calculator resetting every time the notification centre is opened?

System Info: High-Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: This issue is  present in Mojave, btw, though I was sure it didn't used to be the case in earlier OSes.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have found it to be present in macOS High Sierra as well.

Comment: Another beta bug report sent to Apple... let's see... Although in the meantime if someone finds a switch, all well & good.

Comment: You can still use the old-school dashboard calculator, which does persist the calculation.

Comment: True, but I haven't used dashboard in years. I'd kind of forgotten it still existed & perhaps so did Apple. It still looks like OS X 10.9 ;)

Comment: What's wrong with using the Calculator app itself? If you are going to take the effort to launch Notification Center or Dashboard, similar effort can be made to open the Calculator app and keep it running.

Comment: It lacks the convenience of Notification Centre. I either have to keep swapping back to the Space it's on, or have it follow me around all Spaces like a lost puppy. Neither works for me.